# Is there an existing lisp macro for building up a list?

Tags: macros, lisp, elisp

In Python, I am able to use `yield` to build up a list without having to define a temporary variable:

```
def get_chars_skipping_bar(word):
    while word:

        # Imperative logic which can't be
        # replaced with a for loop.
        if word[:3] == 'bar':
           word = word[3:]
        else:
            yield foo[0]
            foo = foo[1:]
```

In elisp, I can't see any way of doing this, either built-in or using any pre-existing libraries. I'm forced to manually build a up a list and call `nreverse` on it. Since this is a common pattern, I've written my own macro:

```
(require 'dash)
(require 'cl)

(defun replace-calls (form x func)
  "Replace all calls to X (a symbol) in FORM,
calling FUNC to generate the replacement."
  (--map
   (cond
    ((consp it)
     (if (eq (car it) x)
         (funcall func it)
       (replace-calls it x func)))
    (:else it))
   form))

(defmacro with-results (&rest body)
  "Execute BODY, which may contain forms (yield foo).
Return a list built up from all the values passed to yield."
  (let ((results (gensym "results")))
    `(let ((,results (list)))
       ,@(replace-calls body 'yield
                        (lambda (form) `(push ,(second form) ,results)))
       (nreverse ,results))))
```

Example usage:

```
(setq foo "barbazbarbarbiz")

(with-results
 (while (not (s-equals? "" foo))
   ;; Imperative logic which can't be replaced with cl-loop's across.
   (if (s-starts-with? "bar" foo)
       (setq foo (substring foo 3))
     (progn
       (yield (substring foo 0 1))
       (setq foo (substring foo 1))))))
```

There must be a better way of doing this, or an existing solution, somewhere in elisp, cl.el, or a library.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/takagi/cl-coroutine

Comment: There's also https://github.com/dcolascione/elisp-generators (though I have not tried it yet myself).

Answer (score 2):

The Python function is actually a *generator*.  In ANSI Common Lisp, we would usually reach for a lexical closure to simulate a generator, or else us a library to define generators directly, like [Pygen](http://cliki.net/pygen). Maybe these approaches can be ported to Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, people just use `push+nreverse` like you do.  If you want to define your macro in a more robust way (e.g. so it doesn't misfire on something like `(memq sym '(yield stop next))`) you could do it as:

```
(defmacro with-results (&rest body)
  "Execute BODY, which may contain forms (yield EXP).
Return a list built up from all the values passed to `yield'."
  (let ((results (gensym "results")))
    `(let ((,results '()))
       (cl-macrolet ((yield (exp) `(push ,exp ,results)))
         ,@body)
       (nreverse ,results))))
```

Comment: I get `Symbol's value as variable is void: results` when using this definition.  I think something is not quite right with the nested backquoting of the `results` gensym, but I can't figure out the correct sequences of quotes and unquotes to splice it in correctly.

Comment: After further experimentation, I think the inner macro definition should have `(push ,exp ,',results)`, but I have only a vague idea of why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```lisp
(setq foo "barbaz")
(cl-loop for i from 0 to (1- (length foo))
         collect (string (aref foo i)))
```

In any case, there's nothing wrong with `push` and `nreverse`.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. `cl-loop` is great when I want to iterate over something, but sometimes I have a complex while loop where I manually iterate. In those cases, I can't use `collect`.

Comment: Then you should give a more appropriate example.

Comment: I have a [real-world example here](https://github.com/Wilfred/mustache.el/blob/b0ea352813592424164520a49e86c04600242752/mustache-lex.el#L4) but I felt it was a little too complex to paste into the question. I've updated the example.

Comment: Just a thought, I often find that text processing similar to that example -- iterating through chunks of text by searching for delimiters -- is easier to do with a temporary buffer than a string in Emacs Lisp. YMMV, and not really relevant to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Lisp is different from Python. yield is not used. I also see the use of coroutine-like constructs for this as a mistake. It's the equivalent of the *come-from* construct. Suddenly routines have multiple context dependent entry points.

In Lisp use functions/closures instead.

In Common Lisp, the LOOP macro allows efficient mappings over vectors. The following code can be abstracted to some mapping function, if preferred:

```
CL-USER 17 > (defun chars-without-substring (string substring)
               (loop with i = 0
                     while (< i (length string))
                     when (and (>= (- (length string) i) (length substring))
                               (string= substring string
                                        :start2 i
                                        :end2 (+ i (length substring))))
                     do (incf i (length substring))
                     else
                     collect (prog1 (char string i) (incf i))))
CHARS-WITHOUT-SUBSTRING

CL-USER 18 > (chars-without-substring "barbazbarbarbiz" "bar")
(#\b #\a #\z #\b #\i #\z)
```